# Temp Message/Page during swap on Azure App Service

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Is there a way to display some type of "Maintenance In Progress" message or web page during a swap operation on Azure App Service?

Comment: If you're talking about while deployment slots are being swapped, that operation should be nearly instantaneous. Is that not the case for you?

Comment: Yes, during the actual swap. It's not quite instantaneous. It takes 20-30 seconds.

Comment: To clarify, after a slot swap, are visitors seeing an actual HTTP error, a timeout, or just a really really slow response when they first hit your site?

Comment: Seems like a really slow response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you swap slots in a Web App, a request is sent to the root of the staging slot before the swap to warm up the instance. There is then an IP switch that occurs, so the swap is instantaneous. The switch doesn't occur until the warm-up requests return.

However, sometimes a single request to the staging slot's root isn't enough to warm up the instance. You can also hit other pages for warm-up by listing them in the web.config file, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <applicationInitialization>
      <add initializationPage="/pagetowarmup1.php" />
      <add initializationPage="/pagetowarmup2.php" />
      <add initializationPage="/pagetowarmup3.php" />
    </applicationInitialization>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My guess is that your site isn't fully warm. Try hitting other pages as part of the warm-up before the slot switch. You can read more about this in the Kudu docs on Github [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-site-swaps).

The swap should then be instantaneous and you shouldn't see the long delay period before your requests get answered. Then you can sidestep your original question of needing to display a "down for maintenance" page.

Comment: PS: Kudu, which basically hosts Web Apps and WebJobs, is open source and available on GitHub. The docs are quite informative. I recommend crawling around in them. I've found stuff there that I never found on StackOverflow or in the documentation on Microsoft.